# (Product Name) on Build App name will not change?

Tags: iphone, sdk

hello i tried adjusting the product name value like this -> string but when i build the program the name does not change is there a trick to it?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you need to set the value for the *Bundle Display Name* key in the Info.pList.  You might be changing the *Bundle name* which doesn't get used for the name under the icon.

Comment: How would i be able to replace the Bundle Display on the pList?

Comment: I am assuming you can see it in the pList viewer.  Just double click on the value and type your new App name.

Answer (score -1):

You can change it in the plist of your application.